# How to achieve the output of the input array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given an array of integers, process each array element and return the resultant array.
If the element is an even no., add 2 to it.
If the element is an odd no., add 1 to it.
The array will not contain any negative integers.
for eg.,

```
Input 1 : {1,2,3,4,5}
Input 2 : 5 (no. of elements in input 1 array)
Output : {2,4,4,6,6}
```

My code :

```
def EvenOddSum(a, n): 
    even = 0
    odd = 0
    for i in range(n): 


        if i % 2 == 0: 
            even += a[i] 
        else: 
            odd += a[i] 

    print("Even index positions sum ", even )
    print ("Odd index positions sum ", odd )
arr=input("Enter array : ")
n = int(input("Enter number of elements in arr : ")) 

print(EvenOddSum(arr, n) )
```

I tried this but this . But code is showing unsupported operand type error. Plus I can't achieve the logic stated in problem.
How to achieve the solution for my problem . Please help.

Comment: You don't need someone to tell you how long an array is in order to iterate over it. `n = int(input("Enter number of elements in arr : "))` is quite pointless. It just gives the user an opportunity to miscount and thus crash the code.

Comment: You have to handle your first input arr. It is not array type is string type and look like this `{1,2,3,4,5}`, and you have to convert them to int to do some operand.

Comment: I could use n=len(arr) but I want to give two inputs. @JohnColeman

Comment: Why on earth would you want to have a pointless but potentially harmful input? If all you want is to have a second `input()` why not `color = input("What is your favorite color?")`. That would be about as relevant.

Comment: @GopisuryaForever It would make more sense if you were to ask the number of elements beforehand and then only get (with `input()`) the appropriate number of elements.

Comment: Okay I will do that @norok2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
arr=input("Enter array : ")
```

gives you a `str`, not a list.  You might want something more like:

```
arr = list(map(int, input("Enter array : ").split()))
```

which takes the `str` input, `split`s it into a `List[str]`, and then `map`s it to a `List[int]`.

Note that this assumes you're entering the array as "1 2 3 4", not some tricky syntax like "{1,2,3,4}" (which you could write more code to handle, but if it's not part of the assignment I wouldn't recommend deliberately making your life more difficult).

You should also define your function to just take the array, rather than the array plus the count (since the array already contains the length).  Then to test it you can simply get the array from stdin and invoke the function all in one step:

```
>>> def even_odd_sum(a):
...     return [i + (2 - i % 2) for i in a]
...
>>> even_odd_sum(list(map(int, input("Enter array: ").split())))
Enter array: 1 2 3 4 5
[2, 4, 4, 6, 6]
```

---

If you wanted to exactly match the funky formatting given in the original question, that's significantly more work than implementing the actual function, but it might look like:

```
from typing import Any, List

def even_odd_sum(a: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    return [i + (2 - i % 2) for i in a]

def input_funky_formatted_list(funk: str) -> List[str]:
    if funk[0] != "{" or funk[-1] != "}":
        raise ValueError("this formatting is insufficiently funky")
    return funk[1:-1].split(",")

def output_funky_formatted_list(arr: List[Any]) -> str:
    return "{" + ",".join(map(str, arr)) + "}"

arr = list(map(int, input_funky_formatted_list(input("Input 1 : "))))
input("Input 2 : ")  # discard this, it serves no purpose
print(f"Output : {output_funky_formatted_list(even_odd_sum(arr))}")
```

Comment: Thankyou @Samwise. But I am require sto give input 1 in the format {1,2,3,4,5} and input two as 5.Output should be {2,4,4,6,6}. Also, my code is not adding 2 to even and 1 to odd and not displaying the output.How to attain that?

Comment: If this is a class assignment, I think you may be misunderstanding what it's asking you to do.

Comment: Thank you so much @Samwise . But is there a simpler way to do this? We can neglect the inputs just the output is needed in this format{2,4,6,6}. Is there any other way to access the elements in the array and add 1 to odd and 2 to even numbers in array?

Comment: Multiple people have now given you detailed answers to this problem, complete with working code, and you don't seem to be reading the responses or even making the bare minimum effort to try running the code from the answers, so I'm not sure what more is to be done here.  Good luck!

Comment: Extremely sorry. I ran each and every input given by everyone and marked the answer but it didn't get recorded due to bad network. I can't upvote as I don't have that much reputation. Sorry @Samwise

Comment: I am really new to this. That's why I asked if there were any other simpler means to do this @Samwise

Comment: Look at the `even_odd_sum` function in the above answer.  That's the simple way to do it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The first problem of the code is that the result of `input()` is a string independent of what you actually type.
To get `arr` to eventually contain an array of numbers (possibly into a `list`), you should parse the string resulting from `input()` or adopt another input strategy (see below on third issue).

Python libraries are incredibly helpful with this, and you could consider using `ast.literal_eval()` for the job, e.g.:

```
import ast


s = '{1,2,3,4,5}'
items = ast.literal_eval('[' + s[1:-1] + ']')
print(items)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you have some freedom over the input, you could spare yourself some work or even take a more direct approach.

---

The second problem is that `EvenOddSum()` (which incidentally is not named according to [typical Python coding style conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) is not implementing the logic to fulfill your expectations.

One way would be:

```
# offsets=(even_offset, odd_offset)
def odd_even_sum(items, offsets=(2, 1)):
    return [item + offsets[item % 2] for item in items]
```

---

The third issue is that if you input a string containing all the array, the information about its length is redundant, unless you make some use of it.

For example, you could use it to check if the array is of the desired length:

```
assert(len(items) == n)
```

or use it to simplify your input:

```
def odd_even_sum(items, offsets=(2, 1)):
    return [item + offsets[item % 2] for item in items]


n = int(input('Array length?'))
items = []
for i in range(n):
    item = int(input(f'Item[{i}]?'))
    items.append(item)
```

---

Putting all this together:

```
def odd_even_sum(items, offsets=(2, 1)):
    return [item + offsets[item % 2] for item in items]


n = int(input('Array length?'))
items = []
for i in range(n):
    item = int(input(f'Item[{i}]?'))
    items.append(item)

new_items = odd_even_sum(items)

print(f' Input:  {items}')
print(f'Output:  {new_items}')
```